# Android APK vs test APK?

Tags: android, android-testing

I see Android creates both a "normal" and an androidTest APK inside the outputs folder?

i.e.

- app-dev-debug.apk
- app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk

Do I need to install both of these if I want to run tests on the device via the debug bridge for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

app-dev-debug is your app, the debug build.  app-dev-debug-androidTest is the apk for your android instrumentation tests.  They have to run on an Android device, so they need to be in an apk.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess both needs to be on the same device running the tests?

Comment: @breakline Don't see it. Do I need additional code to see the testApk. I have /androidTest and /test dir in src/ and also declared AndroidTestRunner in app/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification:

You can install `app-dev-debug.apk` on the device and start using it as an application, no need to install `app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk`.

On the other side, you can install `app-dev-debug-androidTest.apk`, but you cannot use it as an application. It only contains information about android instrumentation tests. And to run this tests, you also need to install `app-dev-debug.apk`. And then you can run them for example with [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsDevice).